# Kendo datepicker directive inside angular directive is not working in firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox, kendo-ui

I have a problem where, I need to generate a kendo-ui directive from my own custom directive. It seems to work fine on chrome but not in firefox. By the way, I also used require.js to load my scripts.

At first, I thought the kendo-ui is problem. But when I pasted the code directly to the html, the date picker worked, so, I believe the problem is with my directive code.

So my question is what is the proper way of doing nested directives that all browsers will accept? or the only problem is lazy loading?